# OAUTH2 server with spring and jwt

Tags: java

I have been asked to create an **oauth2** server to access multiple webapps of our company. And I am following this [github project](https://github.com/absolutegalaber/jwt-oauth2-example).

I dont have  nay idea about creating Oauth2 server.And stuck  while *Getting Access token via authorization code* (followed given process in link).

Comment: "I dont have nay idea about creating Oauth2 server." From your link: "Inside "auth-server" execute "mvn spring-boot:run""

Comment: i have run all  auth,aggregation and resource servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you speak about an OAuth2 server you mean the interface between user storage (f.e. LDAP) and the web aplications?

The easiest way to have an OAuth2 server would be to install [WSO2 IS](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) and configure your LDAP as a secondary user store.

I have not coded the server side of OAuth2 but [Apache OLTU](https://oltu.apache.org/) is a project that has been very helpfull for me. It includes libraries for the server part.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security OAuth2 provides some sample code, one of which is an Auth Server.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

By default, it supports a single user.  But it could be modified to be a more fully-featured Auth Server.  But it does show how to use Spring Security inside the Auth Server as well as implement the OAuth server endpoints and return JWT